# Create a next page for next result set on C# coded asp

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

I have a link that will call on an asp with a code file written in c#. This will build a dynamic page result set query from a ms sql db.

The c# class to run the query is

```
public DataTable GetResultList(string StagingPKID)
{
    DataTable rst = mwGeneric.RunSQL(
        SafewayPlatform.LOGIX_DATABASE.XS,
        @"select Staging_ExtCardID as 'Card/HH number', Status from dbo.CGD_CGLoader_GMStatus with (noLock) where Staging_PKID = "+StagingPKID+" order by LastUpdate desc"
    );
    return rst;
}
```

The result set will be passed to a data table outside the class

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = oCond.GetResultList(StagingPKID);
```

And then build the html table which loops at the dataset to populate the rows

```
        //Building an HTML string.
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

        //Table start.
        html.Append("<table>");

        //Building the Header row.
        html.Append("<tr>");
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            html.Append("<th>");
            html.Append(column.ColumnName);
            html.Append("</th>");
        }
        html.Append("</tr>");

        //Building the Data rows.
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            html.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<td>");
                html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                html.Append("</td>");
            }
            html.Append("</tr>");
        }

        //Table end.
        html.Append("</table>");
```

I place the html on a placeholder

```
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
```

Which in the end put on the html body coded on the asp.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <h2 style="border-radius:10px;background-color:#99ccff;padding:15px;text-align:center;">File Upload Report</h2>
    </div>
    </div>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:PlaceHolder  ID = "PlaceHolder1" runat="server" />  
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

How could I put a limit to display a max of 100 results on the page and have a link and iterate to display the next result set?

I initially thought of using row numbers on the query like below;

```
select 
"Card/HH number",
Status
from (
select
row_number() over (order by LastUpdate desc) as 'rownbr',
Staging_ExtCardID as 'Card/HH number', 
Status 
from dbo.CGD_CGLoader_GMStatus with (noLock)) As Table1
where Table1.rownbr between 1 and 100
```

But I am not sure if this is the right approach as I have to put if conditions to initially check if the result set would be greater than 100 and have the between numbers as variables so that user can navigate back and forth on the result sets.